# How do I access a column that has been stored in temporary table variable in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

How do I access a column that has been stored in temporary table variable?

I tried to access it this way:

```
set @Name = WeekName;
```

but I get an error "column WeekName is undefined".

```
DECLARE @ListOWeekDays TABLE 
                       (
                          DayNumber INT,
                          DayAbb VARCHAR(40), 
                          WeekName VARCHAR(40)
                       )
DECLARE @Name VARCHAR(40);

INSERT INTO @ListOWeekDays
VALUES 
(1, 'Mon', 'Monday')  ,
(2, 'Tue', 'Tuesday') ,
(3, 'Wed', 'Wednesday') ,
(4, 'Thu', 'Thursday'),
(5, 'Fri', 'Friday'),
(6, 'Sat', 'Saturday'),
(7, 'Sun', 'Sunday')    

DELETE @ListOWeekDays 
WHERE DayNumber = 1

UPDATE @ListOWeekDays 
SET WeekName = 'Saturday is holiday'  
WHERE DayNumber = 6

SELECT * FROM @ListOWeekDays

SET @Name = WeekName;
PRINT @Name;
```

Comment: like any other column the only difference is the table being the variable SELECT [DyNumber] FROM @ListOWeekDays;

Answer (score 1):

You need to define a `SELECT` query to get a value from the temporary table variable - just like with any other table, too:

```
SELECT @Name = WeekName
FROM @ListOfWeekDays
-- add whatever condition makes sense here
WHERE DayNumber = 5;
```

Since you're storing the value into a single variable - you **must ensure** that the select only returns a **single row** - e.g. by specifying a value of the primary key or some other unique value.